# Play Framework custom resources: how to copy to target?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a .csv file, that must be read on application startup.

How can I make play to copy this file to target (to "run" or "start" it).

I'm trying to access this file in Global-class with `Global.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.csv")`, but the result is always null.

---

OK - thanks.
I have managed it with my file in conf/ressources folder and loading it with /ressources/file.csv path

Answer (score 3):

You can put it in several places:

- either in the `app` folder
- either in the `conf` folder: I'd go for this one, by creating a `conf/ressources` folder

Comment: in the case of conf/ressources - does the path remains the same? getResourceAsStream("/file.csv")?

Comment: OK - thanks.
I have managed it with my file in conf/ressources folder and loading it with /ressources/file.csv path

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `resources` folder in your `conf` folder, put your file there, and then create an `InputStream` by calling

```
Play.classloader.getResourceAsStream("resources/file.csv");
```

Note that you should not start the path with a `/`, because then the application will not be able to resolve the path and throw a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null` on startup.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in `test/resources/file.csv` folder in the test folder of play project.  Then you can access it in scala with

```
getClass.getResourceAsStream("/file.csv")
```

Check out [this blog post](http://journal.michaelahlers.org/2013/01/play-framework-and-testing-resources.html).